# trouble parsing (soap) result from .NET service (with php)

Tags: php, .net, soap

I'm running into some problems while connecting with a .NET soap server with PHP.
I've run some searches on StackOverflow as well on google, but couldn't find a solution/ same problem.

Here's the thing.
I'm trying to obtain some data from a server. The requests goes well, however the response seems to be invalid.

The response contains only one object element "any" in this object. Raw xml / xsd data is shown.

I've also tried to parse it myself using different methods (as simple_xml & domdocument) however the result is "invalid data/xml"

Has anyone run into this problem or have a proper solution.?

Below you'll find the "result" dump) of the request, if more data is needed please ask.

Cheers
Sebastiaan

```
GetArticleListResult Object
(
    [any] => <xs:schema xmlns:mstns="www.rentplus.be/webservices/ArticleList.xsd" xmlns="www.rentplus.be/webservices/ArticleList.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="dsArticleList" targetNamespace="www.rentplus.be/webservices/ArticleList.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"><xs:element name="dsArticleList" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="ArticleList"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Article_Key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Warehouse_Number" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Date_Creation" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Date_Last_Modification" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><dsArticleList xmlns="www.rentplus.be/webservices/ArticleList.xsd"><ArticleList diffgr:id="ArticleList1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><Article_Key>GELUM-LE400</Article_Key><Warehouse_Number>01</Warehouse_Number><Date_Creation>0001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</Date_Creation><Date_Last_Modification>2011-08-10T00:00:00+02:00</Date_Last_Modification></ArticleList></dsArticleList></diffgr:diffgram>
)
```

Comment: I don't know what you are using as SOAP Server, but based on that dump: namespace urls in `<xs:schema>` should be absolute URLs, and document contains no document element or additional content. You have two top level elements: `<xs:schema>` and `<diffgr:diffgram>` - that is called _malformed xml_

Comment: HI Confused-Demon.  Thanks for your reply. And thanks for confirming the invalid xml issue.. I addressed it to the guys who own's the server aswell, however their response was that it was a default .NET implementation so it could be wrong :)...

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue myself.  I know very little about XML and SOAP, but from the research  I did, the default .net web-services makes a mess with namespaces and other wrappers.  Further, the php soap client makes it worse and fails to make a proper object.  The response you get is 1/2 object and 1/2 XML.  Make no sense, right!

Well, I load the "any" element of the object and loaded it into a

```
$wsdl= {url of your WSDL}; //assuming its some WSDL generated by MS .net or visual studio.  Something a normal human WOULD NOT WRITE. 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);        //create a soap client and load WSDL
$result = $client->GetQuote($param);    //get result of the soap call
$quote = $result->GetQuoteResult;       //Get the response-- its an object.  this part is weird because it's an object containing xml parts.  There is no easy path to use it.

$xml_object = new SimpleXMLElement($quote->any);  //Grab the xml part and load as partial XML --> this took forever to figure out. anger here!!

foreach ($xml_object->Quote->Plans as $plan){       //here in my data, the XML becomes a standard ARRAY--> really getting mad now.
    //grab a few items out of the array for kicks.  Don't grab all of them, cuz some switch back to XML --> make up your mind.
    $item_names=array("QuoteID","ProductID","ProductName","PlanTypeID",
        "PlanName", "Deductible","Coinsurance", "CoverageAmount",
        "Duration", "FirstPayment", "RecurringPayment"  );
    foreach ($item_names as $item_name){
        print "$item_name=".$plan->$item_name.",  ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
print "</pre>";
</pre>
```

And now your have retrieved the information that you wanted from the visual studio .net webserivce. easy,  right!!

Answer (score -1):

Below I present how I handle SOAP request and response. You are getting `Object` containing `any` containing your data, so do `Object->any` like so:

```
$WS_settings = array(
    'address' => 'http://example.com.asmx?wsdl',
    'username' => 'login',
    'password' => 'pass'
);
$WS_client = new SoapClient($WS_settings['address']);

$WS_params = new stdClass();
$WS_params->Username = $WS_settings['username'];
$WS_params->Password = $WS_settings['password'];

$WS_params->IdBrand = 1;
$WS_params->IdModel = 2;
$WS_params->IdApplication = 3;

$result = $WS_client->Get_Products($WS_params)->Get_ProductsResult->any;
var_dump($result);
```